# Route with multiple paramaters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the route:

`match "/invite/create/:first_name/:last_name/:email/:phone" => 'invite#create'`

and when I try:

`http://localhost:3000/invite/create/bill/bob/bob@gmail.com/1234567890`

I get a `No route matches [GET] "/invite/create/bill/bob/bob@gmail.com/1234567890"` error.

Whats wrong with my route?

Comment: do you have any other routes with "invite"?

Comment: @Lucas just `match "/invite" => 'invite#index'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have other routes that start with the same url fx `/invite`, then is it important that you define `match "/invite/create/:first_name/:last_name/:email/:phone" => 'invite#create'` first.

However this is not a very good practice, you should always do a post request when creating new records.

Comment: Ive got rid of the other route and it still doesnt work, I need it to be a `GET` request as I am writing a an web service for an iOS app.

Comment: Then use `get` instead of `match` :). However i can't explain your problem, i will need more information. Just a guess however: have you tried without @ in the email? Don't know if that brakes anything...

Comment: Also you have a `InviteController` with a aciton `create` right :) ?